# sscanf with std::string_view

Tags: c++, linux, posix, c++20

`std::string_view` is not 0-terminated so I can't use `sscanf`. Microsoft CRT have [_snscanf_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snscanf-s-snscanf-s-l-snwscanf-s-snwscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170), which accepts buffer length. Is there any POSIX alternative?

```
TIMESTAMP_STRUCT StringToTimestamp(std::string_view dTime, bool dayfirst) noexcept
{
    TIMESTAMP_STRUCT t{};
    int res;
    if (dayfirst)
        res = _snscanf_s(dTime.data(), dTime.size(), "%2hu.%2hu.%4hd %2hu:%2hu:%2hu", &t.day, &t.month, &t.year, &t.hour, &t.minute, &t.second);
    else
        res = _snscanf_s(dTime.data(), dTime.size(), "%4hd-%2hu-%2hu %2hu:%2hu:%2hu", &t.year, &t.month, &t.day, &t.hour, &t.minute, &t.second);

    if (res == 6)
        return t; // success

    if (!dTime.empty() && dTime != "0") // log if not empty or 0
        Common::Log::Instance()->TraceFatal("StringToTimestamp failed");
    return {};
}
```

Comment: There isn't, for the simple reason that `sscanf` and friends are C library functions and they have no knowledge, or will ever have any knowledge, of any C++ class.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik there are a lot of C functions accepting non terminated strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet but there were some extensions.
You can still use sscanf. Just ensure you do not read pass the end of your data.

Note that all format specifiers have width parameter which specifies MAXIMIM number of characters to be read.

In your example, actually all specifiers have width.
So you can just check std::string_view.size() against your formats.
std::string_view.size() >= 19
and
std::string_view.size() >= 21

And for your example there is strftime which includes maxsize parameter.

Comment: `strftime` is for foramtting (`printf` like)

Comment: There is `std::get_time`, but it works only with streams and `ostrstream` is deprecated in C++98 and `ospanstream` is available only in C++23.